# How can I improve my poorly-received questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'd like to improve my question-asking, as my only two questions ([question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625346/design-pattern-for-managing-groups-of-tasks) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918691/java-reflection-to-call-overloaded-method-area-equalsarea)) were poorly received. I really put effort into those questions, and I believe I followed all the guidelines on the ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page, so I'm here seeking more advice.

### Help Page Guidelines

1. Search, and research.

   - In question 1, I mentioned that I tried to search for similar questions, but the question itself is hard to describe, and I still don't know how I'd search for it. I also state what approach I am aware of ("where classes register themselves with other classes") and why I think it doesn't solve my problem.
   - In question 2, evidence of research is prominent in the first sentence, as I cite an existing question and state how my question differs. I also show my current attempt, which illustrates two approaches I've tried (`cls.cast(o2)` and reflection).
2. Write a title that summarizes the specific problem.

   - Question 1 is titled "Design pattern for managing groups of tasks". This describes what I want and what it's for. I admit that "managing groups of tasks" is not the best description of the *design pattern*, but since I don't know the appropriate design, the best I can do is describe my objective.
   - Question 2 is titled "Java reflection to call overloaded method Area.equals(Area)". This succinctly describes what I want, using a technique that I think is relevant. Or maybe I shouldn't have prescribed the solution in my question? The commenters seem to think that reflection is overkill.
3. Introduce the problem before you post any code.

   - Question 1 begins by describing the use-case for my requested design pattern, giving context as to the number of tasks and my goals, before code is introduced.
   - Question 2 begins by summarizing the origins the problem (that `Area` overloads instead of overriding `Object.equals(Object)`) and what my goal is (to call `Area.equals(Area)`), before giving my attempt in code.
4. Help others reproduce the problem.

   - Question 1 doesn't have a problem to "reproduce" because I'm asking for design advice. Nevertheless, I provide code that compiles (minus some ellipses) that illustrates my intent.
   - Question 2 provides commented code that compiles and runs, to illustrate what I've tried, what works, and what doesn't. Yet, there's a close vote for not providing a MCVE.
5. Include all relevant tags.

   - Question 1 is about a `design pattern` in `Java`. I can't think of other relevant tags, although as a new user I'm also not very familiar with all of them.
   - Question 2 is about using `reflection` to force calling a particular `equals` implementation in `Java`, and again I don't know what else to add.
6. Proof-read before posting!

   - Yes, I have proofread. Several times.
7. Post the question and respond to feedback.

   - I promptly responded to answers and questions in both cases.
   - In question 2, after I realized that commenters were missing some details, I edited the question (twice).
8. Look for help asking for help.

   - That's why I'm here.

### Other Common Pitfalls

1. The XY problem.

   - I think I avoided this in question 1 by describing my use-case.
   - I don't think I have the XY problem in question 2, but I have the impression that the commenters believe I do.
2. Questions that are too broad.

   - Question 1 is broad by necessity because I'm asking for design advice. I don't think it's *too* broad because I've provided my specific context and constraints. To reduce the broadness of my question, I included an ordered list of "desirable properties" to help answerers evaluate different options.
   - Question 2 isn't broad at all -- I have a specific situation and I want to obtain a specific behavior.
3. Formatting.

   - I spent a lot of time making sure that the questions are presentable.

### Possible Issues

Here are some possible issues that I'm aware of:

1. Question 1 might not be described in a crystal clear manner. The question was hard to write because I wanted to remain open to design options that I hadn't considered, so I didn't want to be too specific about my current approach. However, I did my best to illustrate what I know and what I need.
2. In question 1, I didn't explicitly say what was "silly and error-prone" with my last code block. In particular, I didn't want a hardcoded list of classes *anywhere*, which was maybe not clear.
3. Question 1 could be read as "I have a problem with a bunch of detailed criteria, someone solve this for me." Even though I described an initial "silly" approach, I can see how the question could still be read in this way, and I'm not sure how to avoid this.
4. Question 2 required a couple edits to improve clarity.
5. Question 2 is basically asking "is there a better way than the 'heavy-handed' approach I just described", and it appears that the answer is "no". That makes answering difficult and the question not-so-useful for future visitors, but how was I supposed to know that before asking?
6. I'm a new user, and when I posted these questions I had single-digit reputation. I've worked hard to answer questions the last few days to improve any "first impressions". (That was a learning process in itself, as I got plenty of downvotes!)

And after scrutinizing my questions I feel like I'm grading an English-class essay. I hope I don't need to apply the same scrutiny to my future questions, since that's probably not the ideal mindset for someone posting questions on a site for that purpose. It's also somewhat disheartening to see other positively-voted questions that I perceive to be less polished, or maybe I'm just being arrogant.

Thanks for helping me become a better question asker. And if there are issues with *this question* please let me know as well.

Comment: I would not consider one downvote for each of these "poorly received" - it could be one guy having a bad day. That said, there may be ways to improve your questions (e.g. make them more specific), but I wouldn't say a single downvote merits a deep analysis.

Comment: Both downvotes happened within a few minutes after each question was posted, and the questions were posted days apart, so it most likely wasn't the same user downvoting. I also got a close vote.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean? I'm aware of what the XY problem is, are you saying that my questions suffer from it? Or maybe _this_ question suffers from it?

Comment: When you get *what the heck* comments from SO users then that is always a good hint that they don't understand why you are tackling a problem a certain way.  If you then also have to get snippy with "don't lecture me about the needs of my application" to ward them off then it turns into a lost cause.  So boilerplate advice is to focus more on the needy and less on the solution.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, I see your point: in question 2, I just stated _what_ I wanted, and not _why_ I wanted it, and that led to confusion.

Comment: @Vega rep is copied over from main to meta at certain intervals. It may not always show the same

Comment: That might very well become a canonical for such questions.

Comment: The way that you say `Phew, that was a long post ` shows that despite your extensive efforts, you still haven't quite got it.  You are very close though and have done much better than most others. SO is not a forum.  It does not have posts, it has questions and answers.

Comment: I somewhat agree with the first one being opinion-based, but IMO the second one is a good question, so I've upvoted.

Comment: @JK. I think the defintion is `post ::= question | answer`? It even appears in the [revision link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/366306/revisions).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think your first question is poor; it's clear you have a well-structured scenario and have put a lot of effort into it. The two close votes on it are currently for Too Broad and POB. These are the prerogative of the close voters, more or less, though I would say that, even though the general question of "design advice" is a POB subject to be avoided, your question lays out specific goals and requirements that your desired solution would meet, and the guidance for asking opinion-based questions states that they're allowed *if* they invite answers to:

- explain how and why they chose their solution
- have longer rather than shorter answers
- are based on experience rather than opinion
- are impartial
- and backed up with facts/references.

And the answers provided seem to do most, if not all, of those pretty well.

As for your second question, it has received a close vote for lacking a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I haven't touched Java since high school, so I can't speak to whether that's the case here. Also, there's some confusion about your scenario in the comments under your second question, which Hans Passant has already brought up above. This could potentially lend credence to someone closing the question as Unclear based on your current premise/question's structure.

Further, your second question (by your own admission) is just asking "is there a better way?". While it's possible (see my response covering question one above) to ask opinion questions in a constructive and well-received way, it's still hard, and questions asking about a better way in broad terms often are poorly-received here, because they tend to be... well... broad and opinion-based. The only concern you've given for why you want a better way is that the approach you are thinking about is "a little heavy-handed".

This second question *could* be rephrased to ask "How can I do this *without* using reflection", and then explaining exactly why reflection is not useful for you in non-opinionated terms. That would at least show to readers that you have thoroughly considered a solution and found it wanting for *reasons*, rather than just the sake of wanting something different.

---

All in all your questions are not terrible, and I agree with jpp that one downvote is not necessarily a poor reception. Your questions are thorough and the effort you've put in them is clear, despite what issues they may have... a little fine-tuning and they could be great questions.

On the subject of great questions, *this* meta question of yours is great, and thank you for coming here and asking in earnest about improving your content! It's a much nicer approach to see from people than self-vandalizing or insults to other users in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately my questions have attracted some attention and Question 1 is now on hold (POB). You seem to hold the opinion that my question is allowed, but can you also suggest specific ways I can make Question 1 less "opinion-based"? How is a design-pattern question supposed to be asked?

Comment: @pkpnd It's a tough call; usually high-level design questions are considered appropriate for Software Engineering, rather than Stack Overflow. Questions relating to design here should definitely focus on the programmatic implementation of the design and specific problems you have with it.

Comment: Ah thanks, that's what I was missing. I wasn't aware until now that Software Engineering was the more appropriate place for this.

Comment: @pkpnd I will throw in an obligatory "take the tour" comment before posting questions there... that way you can see what kind of questions the tour recommends, at least.