# How to improve this downvoted question

Tags: support, specific-question

I posted this question in 2016 and has some down votes.

Link to the topic: [how to use if then else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093823/how-to-use-if-else-while)

I would like to receive some help to improve this question.

I would like to explain what the reason is for this posting:

When I started programming I had loads of questions. 4 years ago I didn't know much about programming. I was often obsessed with solving the problem and did not take enough time to read the guidelines well of this - by the way - terrific programming community.

The result is that a few times I could not post at Stack Overflow. But for some reason, without me reacting on it, the ban was solved.

Some posts receive downvotes and comments about the reason for doing that.

I also learned a few things. The main thing I learned: read and search thoroughly before asking. Many things are already there and duplicates are often not necessary.

I hope users here can give a few good recommendations to post good questions. (Not a link to the user guidelines, but some good hints for example)

I would also like to know what criteria are used for not giving people a posting opportunity (temporarily).

Comment: When you're under a question ban (because of multiple bad questions), you have a chance every 6 month to post a new question, if this question is well received (upvoted), the ban is lifted, if it gets downvotes the ban is reset for 6 more months

Comment: You say "not a link to the user guidelines", but [ask] has a lot of good recommendations, as do the pages linked to at the end. Anything written here would be the same as those recommendations, or as answers to other questions, like [Is there anyway to further improve my bad question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269106) or [How can I improve my poorly-received questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366306).

Comment: @Tensibai Not exactly like that. If you get *heavily* downvoted on previous question and only *a bit* upvoted on new one then you may still be banned. (IIRC)

Comment: @user this is explained in the link I gave in my answer, this comment was mostly to pinpoint a ban doesn't come for one question alone and to give a first insight on the q ban

Answer (score 7):

What I think can be improved in your question:

First: review your code block, most IDE will help your reflow your code into something more readable with proper indentation inside blocks, then copy it into the question, select the code and click the `{}` button to add the 4 spaces (or use the ctrl+k keyboard shortcut).

Second: don't answer in your question, if this is your solution put in in an answer.

Third: explain what you searched, why it failed or why what you found doesn't seems the solution to your problem (show your efforts)

Some good guidelines on writing a question can be found on Jon Skeet's blog post [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (I know you did ask specifically for hints and not a link, but that's impractical in an answer with reasonable length)

For the details on question ban see [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand the subject material, but when I read this:

> The script here fetches data from the database. **The goal is that the input $subj might possibly not find a string but it is also possible to find it. Both actions are significant!**
>
> **The idea is that I use if ... else ... while.**

.... I simply cannot figure out what you are talking about.

So my first suggestion is to rewrite the two sentences highlighted in clear English.

My second suggestion is that your Question actually *reads* like a request for somene to write / complete some code for you, or solve a problem for you.  The consensus is that that kind of "question" is inappropriate for SO.

So, if that is not what you meant, then I suggest that you **remove** this sentence:

> But here I'm completely stuck and I really hope someone can help me solving it.

and in its place add something that tells the reader what specifically you are stuck on.

In general:

- Questions need to be specific and concrete.
- "I am stuck, please help me" is not a question: it is a request for assistance.
- Avoid explicitly or implicitly asking people to write / correct / complete code for you.

---

If your real goal in asking your Question was to get someone to solve your problem for you, I don't think there is any way to "dress it up" to make more acceptable.  Just don't ask questions like that in the first place.

To be blunt, if you came to SO because you want someone to write your code / solve your problems for you ... hire a consultant.